# Unable to access files using BrickFTP API with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api-design

So I am attempting to access my files from BrickFTP through an API call using Node. I have followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://developers.brickftp.com/?shell--json#authentication-with-a-session) but still get a 401 error when attempting to get a list of the files:

```
Unauthorized. The API key or Session token is either missing or invalid.
```

I do want to clarify that I am able to generate a session token but I still do not have access.

The weirdest part is when I use Postman to run the calls it is able to start a session and list the folder's contents. Any help to the right direction will be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const requestPromise = require("request-promise");

// Get token to begin session
const response = await requestPromise({
   uri: 'https://MYDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/sessions.json',
   method: 'POST',
   body: {username: "myUserName", password:"myAwesomeSecretPassword"},
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   json: true
 });

const sessionID = response.id; 

// Get files from folder
const files = await requestPromise({
     uri: 'https://MYDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/folders/?sort_by[modified_at_datetime]=desc',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {[sessionID]: '', Accept: 'application/json' },
     json: true
});
```

Comment: You have to be setting the header for the sessionId wrong. There’s no way that server is looking for an empty string. Maybe there is a different field for the token and you should assign the `sessionId` to it? perhaps `X-BRICK-REAUTHENTICATION`?

Comment: That's what I thought also but it says it could be an empty string or some random letter like 'x'. That's why I'm at a total lost. 

This is what is shown in the documentation: 

        curl https://SUBDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/rest/v1/folders/Engineering%20Candidates/R%c3%a9sum%c3%a9s \
    -u YOUR_API_KEY:x \
    -H 'Accept: application/json'

But I'm not too familiar with curl. But i'll give reauthentication a shot

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u This should help you figure out what they mean

Comment: Thank you, I actually gave that manpage a look. I guess I just never really knew how to change it to JavaScript format.

Comment: try `\`https://${sessionId}:x@MYDOMAIN.brickftp.com/api/etc\``...

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually did some digging. And there was 2 ways of logging in, either through an API key or a created session key. However, in order to retrieve the data you had to use the appropriate log in. I was mixing a session_ID with an API key

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!